# Get Non repeating elements on 2 column and have 1:1 records between both columns, dedup in sequential order pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe with 2 columns. I need to get a dataframe without any repeating elements in the preceeding rows of that column. If an element is repeated then than entire row should be ignored.

Input dataframe:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 4 |
| C | 4 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 5 |
| F | 4 |
| G | 7 |
| D | 8 |
| H | 9 |
| I | 9 |
| H | 10 |
| I | 10 |

Expected Result dataframe :

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 5 |
| G | 7 |
| H | 9 |
| I | 10 |

I've tried using window functions to remove duplicates. But it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: The problem is that your case depends on how your table is sorted. Therefore, it does not work with Spark. If you have the B lines before the A lines, the output will be different. However, Spark does not work like this; the output will always be the same regardless of the order. This means that your logic is flawed.

Comment: Thanks for you response @Steven Do we have any workaround to achieve this 1:1 mapping across Column1 and Column2 records, without using UDF!

Comment: you need at least one extra column to maintain the order.

Comment: Let's say suppose we create another column for the order using monotonically_increasing_id() or row_number(). Is it possible to eliminate the repeating element's row using the column we created?!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df.withColumn(
    "r", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("column1").orderBy("column2"))
).where("r=1").drop("r")
```

I create a row number for each line. The first line of each group (partition) of column1 is a 1, therefor, I just need to filter on that value.

---

**EDIT**

Doing the same thing twice to remove all duplicates :

```py
df.withColumn(
    "r", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("column1").orderBy("column2"))
).where("r=1").drop("r").withColumn(
    "r", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("column2").orderBy("column1"))
).where("r=1").drop("r")
```

Comment: With this piece of code we will get row F as well in the result. Which is not expected. We should not consider that row as 4 in Column2 is already included.

Comment: @moulilee, you just need to execute the deduplication process twice. First, use the code to deduplicate based on column1. Then, repeat the process by swapping column1 and column2 to deduplicate based on column2.

Comment: how should we handle the case i mentioned in the question. P.S: I'll edit the question for that situation

Answer (score 0):

in spark-sql use row_number function

```
val dF2 = Seq(
("A",1),
("B",2),
("A",3),
("C",3),
("C",4),
("C",4),
("D",4),
("E",5),
("F",4),
("G",7),
("D",8)
).toDF("Column1","Column2")

dF2.createOrReplaceTempView("dF2")

spark.sql(""" 
select column1, column2
from 
(
select column1, column2, 
       row_number() over (partition by column2 order by column1) rn
from
(
select column1, column2, 
       row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column2) rn
  from dF2
) s where rn=1
) s where rn=1

""").show(100, false)
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|A      |1      |
|B      |2      |
|C      |3      |
|D      |4      |
|E      |5      |
|G      |7      |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: With this piece of code we will get row F as well in the result. Which is not expected. We should not consider that row as 4 in Column2 is already included.

Comment: @moulilee fixed

Comment: for the case i mentioned in edit of question. Still not getting expected result

Comment: @moulilee Please double-check that you are using correct partition by and order by in both row_number() calculations.  I have tested the code and got results as expected. See the update code, you ca`n run it and check. It is in Scala in upper level, but you can easily convert to Python.   Note that partition by and order by are different in first and second row_number

Comment: Still for the case which I added doesn't giving me expected result.